# windows workflow foundation and ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, workflow-foundation

Can I create a sequential workflow using windows workflow foundation in web application (ASP.NET MVC 5) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely. Just use WorkflowApplication / WorkflowInvoker to execute the workflow (.xaml) you design.

Comment: Samples can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd560894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for response, have you a tutorial with web application MVC 5 (with  engine view razor) with workflow foundation ?

Comment: If you understand MVC well then you won't be bothered by incorporating WF into the V (view). Once you agree with this then there is no difference for using WF in MVC or any other types of application.